# please can anyone explain this error in logcat

Tags: android

```
06-26 17:07:09.898: E/AndroidRuntime(380): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 17:07:09.898: E/AndroidRuntime(380): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.mythrii.email.Mail
06-26 17:07:09.898: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at org.mythrii.email.Email$1.onClick(Email.java:19)
06-26 17:07:09.898: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-26 17:07:09.898: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
06-26 17:07:09.898: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-26 17:07:09.898: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-26 17:07:09.898: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-26 17:07:09.898: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-26 17:07:09.898: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 17:07:09.898: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-26 17:07:09.898: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-26 17:07:09.898: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-26 17:07:09.898: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It means `Mail.java` doesn't exist i think.

Comment: are you using any external library?

Comment: Shouldn't `org.mythrii.email.Mail` be `org.mythrii.email.Email`?

Comment: thanks for your reply ya Mail.java is present in that file mail code is present

Comment: ya iam using external lib file Mail.jar,activation.jar and additional.jar files

Comment: [Follow the steps properly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/940096)

Comment: Is that from a library?  If it is, the library jar needs to be in the `/libs` directory.

Comment: Try to clean your project. Or try to restart your work-space and run it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to create a folder named "libs" in the project directory and copying all the external jar files there.

For further explanation, you can refer to this link.

http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

Comment: i already created lib folder and add all jar files but no use

Comment: the name of the folder should be "libs"

Comment: If it still does not work, try adding the jar file to the project build path by right clicking on the jar file and "Add it to build".

Answer (score 1):

I think what you face is that your code compiles , but @ run time it crashes . How do i solve this , create a `libs` folder in your project inside eclipse(if its not exist)  and add the jar file that contains the `org.mythrii.email.Mail` class inside the `libs` folder , Then run you app .